# Does this site permit to post/edit by an anonymous user?

Tags: discussion

I posted [an answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/41073/3869) under the question [What was the reason for Swami Vivekananda's Death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17761/3869)

Today morning, I had  received a message that someone wants to propose changes in my answer.  There is nothing wrong, if someone wants to improve the answer.

To my surprise, it [was done by some an anonymous user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30102).

My question is ***Who is the an anonymous user?***

Does this site permit  to post/edit by an anonymous user?

or

Is it a malware run by some third party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any unregistered user is allowed to improve a question or an answer on main site. Since they  are unregistered, they are called anonymous users. For example check this screenshot:

[image]

I am not logged in as you can see in top right highlighted part, but I can still see an option to improve the question highlighted at the bottom left. This is feature by design. Because any edit done by anonymous users will go through approval process. So it can be moderated easily.

There is already a thread posted about this issue on meta long back, read this here: [Strange suggested edit from anonymous user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203397/206319)

Comment: Allowing outsiders, without registration, to edit the existing answers is not a good practice, in my opinion.

Comment: Since approval process is there, I see no harm in that! @SrimannarayanaKV I have added meta thread in my answer. Read it once

Comment: Still, I don't feel it is a good practice.  Anyways, if it is allowed by the site administrators by themselves, I will not comment further on this issue.

Comment: Yeah! It's allowed across SE sites! Hinduism SE is not an exception. @SrimannarayanaKV